# ASP.NET Routing, make i possible to route to a .zip file for download

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I'm using ASP.NET Routing in my webapp.
On my site I have a .zip file that I want to users to be able to download.
But I get error saying: "There is no build provider registered for the extension '.zip'. "

What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET MVC try using FileContentResult Class
[msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.web.mvc.filecontentresult.aspx)